# accessing info from a custom gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have written a simple custom gesture recognizer like this:

```
@interface myRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {

    NSString * _name;
    CGPoint _startPoint;  
}

- (void)resetMe;
- (void)reset;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end
```

and I have initiated it like this:

```
myRecognizer *recognizer = [[myRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognize_myRecognizer:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

so far so good. and I have my action here:

```
-(void)didRecognize_myRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)theRecognizer
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
```

ok, this is working fine so far, and everything is good. But, here is my question, how can I get access to the _name property I created in my custom gesture in the //do stuff here arear? Basically, I would like to make many gestures, but only have a single method used for the actions, depending on the name of the gesture. In debugging mode I can clearly see the _name variable, but if I try writing code like this: theRecognizer._name, I'm told that there is no "_name" property in UIGEestureRecognizers. if I change the method to this:

```
-(void)didRecognize_myRecognizer:(myRecognizer*)theRecognizer
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
```

the same thing happens. and, that wouldn't be good anyway because i want to use the method for all of the gesture recognizers i make. am I clueless? show me the light!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have to declare an accessor for the instance variable. Dot notation is for properties not instance variables. Declare `name` as property.

Then, You can check the class of the gesture recognizer and extract the name.

```
NSString * name = nil;
if ( [theRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[myRecognizer class]] ) {
    name = [(myRecognizer *)theRecognizer name];
}
```

Comment: Add `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;` to the interface and `@synthesize name = _name;` to the implementation of the custom subclass. Now you can access and set the property using `myRecognizerInstance.name`. If possible, use capitalized class names rather than camel case as the convention is to use camel case for variables.